# Big Picture Notification in android

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I have done android push notification using FCM.But when I am trying the big picture notification it's not showing the full  image in the notificationn bar.Left and Right side of the image is getting cropped.Please let me know how to fix the issue.i tried by giving 512*256 image and 600*300 size images.

Comment: Why don't you post a screen shot of what you are getting and what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Glide library for loading image from URL... Then I have loaded this image using Big Picture Notification.

```
public class ImageNotification extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Bitmap image ,bmp;
    public NotificationCompat.Builder nb;
    final String url = "https://www.google.es/images/srpr/logo11w.png";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_notification);


    }

    public void createNotification(View view) {
        // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
        // notification is selected
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

        nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        nb.setContentTitle("Image Notification");
        nb.setContentText("Set Content text");
        nb.setTicker("Set Ticker text");


        Glide.
                with(this).
                load(url).
                asBitmap()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100) {
                          @Override
                          public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {

                              NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bps = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(resource);
                              bps.setSummaryText("Summary text appears on expanding the notification");
                              nb.setStyle(bps);

                          }
                      });






        TaskStackBuilder TSB = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        TSB.addParentStack(ImageNotification.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        TSB.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                TSB.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        nb.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        nb.setAutoCancel(true);
        nb.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        nb.setSound(alarmSound, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(11221, nb.build());
    }

}
```

If you loading the image from mipmap or drawable you can replace the code written for glide library using the below code

```
Bitmap bitmap_image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.picture);
      NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle s = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap_image);
       s.setSummaryText("Summary text appears on expanding the notification");
        nb.setStyle(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the complete code for BigPicture  from FCM Notification:**

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

  private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap,NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String  message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message_alertnoti).setTicker(title).setWhen(0);
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName("com.packageName", "com.packageName.activity.YourActivity"); // give any activity name which you want to open
    try {
        intent.putExtra("regId", userInfo.selectOneField(UserInfo.DEVICE_ID));
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    mBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorOrange));
    mBuilder.setContentText(message);
    mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap));/*Notification with Image*/
    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    mBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[0]);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}

/**
 * Downloading push notification image before displaying it in
 * the notification tray
 */
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your drawable name and resize it to 96*96 and put it in drawable-xhdpi folder.and use renamed drawable in notification.

Here is code for **BigPicture** Notification:

```
     Bitmap icon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.k);

            NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPicture = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
            bigPicture.bigPicture(icon1);


             NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                         .setContentTitle("Big picture")

                         .setStyle(bigPicture);

             NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
             mNotificationManager.notify(4, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I tried with 96*96 now the length is fine but height making problem.Is there any way handle it from code.

Comment: try with put image in xxhdpi and xxxhdpi folders.and then also it not works then put this image in 48*48 and put in xhdpi.

Comment: How it will work if the image is coming from back end?

Comment: Yes.I am setting the image from url

Comment: use imageview for notification icon?